# jquery serialize and .net controls

Tags: asp.net, .net, jquery, webforms

i use jquery serialize() with asp.net server controls.

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddFirmaAd" runat="server" Width="180" Height="25">
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

when i print the array

```
ajaxRequest("AjaxServices/Insert.aspx", $("#aspnetForm").serialize(), $('#returnMessage'), 0, $(this)); 

 function ajaxRequest(pageURL, queryString, putArea, timeout, disabledCtrl) {
        if (disabledCtrl != null)
            disabledCtrl.attr("disabled", "true");
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            timeout: timeout,
            cache: false,
            url: pageURL + "?" + queryString,  


alert($("#aspnetForm").find("input,textarea,select,hidden").not("#__VIEWSTATE,#__EVENTVALIDATION").serialize());
```

it prints ddFirmaAd client name on window ="ct100%24ct100%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ddFirmaAd = 2 "

i want to get ddFirmaAd.selectedValue on code behind

```
string value = request.queryString("ddFirmaAd");
```

but the control name = ct100%24ct100%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ddFirmaAd

how to i use serialize() and .net controls ?

Comment: @Robotsushi: ASP.NET automatically sets `name` attributes of elements to fully-qualified control hierarchy names, making them barely usable in code outside of the ASP.NET server control ecosystem.  He's serializing with jQuery, which uses the `name` attribute to build the form values (since an HTTP POST uses the `name` attribute to identify `form` elements).  Presumably to send them to a different page (not the post-back-able page that has the controls).  Thus, difficult query string values.

Comment: Why would you want to serialize .net controls ? (not criticizing just curious about your use case)

Comment: i have dynamic controls which are listing data from datebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `string value = request.QueryString(ddFirmaAd.ClientID);`

but if you pass these values to a different page you can hack it like this:

`string value = GetValueById("ddFirmaAd");`

```
private string GetValueById(string endsWith)
    {
        var qs = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString;
        foreach(var key in qs)
        {
            string skey = key.ToString();
            if(skey.EndsWith(endsWith))
            {
                return qs[skey];
            }

        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Not saying that it's correct. Simply cannot come up with anything better based on the currently provided problem description.

You can configure [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) to static but then maintaining unique IDs becomes your responsibility and might lead to hard to find client side bugs.

Comment: it cant. i post the datas on another file with serialize() method

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Asp.Net 4.0 you can use ClientIdMode = "Static" in order to let the client id the same as the id. For more information, check http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/hima/archive/2010/07/16/all-about-client-id-mode-in-asp-net-4.aspx