# Ajax POST not sending correct form value

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax

When I submit my form through AJAX the values of the form are not correct. In this snippet of code, through AJAX the value is always 15 minutes (however a normal POST submit works fine!)

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
          $('#BookButton').click(function (event) {
              var form = $('#Form1');
              $.ajax({

                  type: form.attr('method'),
                  url: form.attr('action'),
                  data: $("#BookRoom :input").serialize()
              }).done(function (data) {
                  $('#BookRoom').modal('hide');
                  if (data.ResponseType == 0) {
                      $('#SuccessMsg').text('Meeting Booked');
                      $('#SuccessMessage').modal('show');
                  }
                  else if (data.ResponseType == 1) {
                      $('#SuccessMsg').text('There are conflicts');
                      $('#SuccessMessage').modal('show');
                  }

                  else {
                      $('#SuccessMsg').text('Data: ' + data.ResponseType);
                      $('#SuccessMessage').modal('show');
                  }


                  // Optionally alert the user of success here...


                  setTimeout(function () { $('#SuccessMessage').modal('hide'); }, 3000);
              }).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ){
                  // Optionally alert the user of an error here...
                  alert("Error submitting AJAX request" + textStatus);
              });
              event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting via the browser.
          });
      });
```

```
<form id="Form1" action="iPadLayout.aspx?RoomID=1" method="post" runat="server">


<div class="modal fade" id="BookRoom" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="BookRoomLabel" aria-hidden="true">

 <div class="modal-dialog">
 <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">   </button>
     <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Book This Room</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>This room is available for the rest of the day</p>

         <asp:DropDownList ID="MeetingLength" runat="server">
             <asp:ListItem Text="15 Minutes" Value="15" Selected="true" /> 
             <asp:ListItem Text="30 Minutes" Value="30" /> 
             <asp:ListItem Text="45 Minutes" Value="45" /> 
             <asp:ListItem Text="1 Hour" Value="60" /> 
             <asp:ListItem Text="1.5 Hours" Value="90" /> 
             <asp:ListItem Text="2 Hours" Value="120" /> 
</asp:DropDownList>



  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   <asp:Button type="button" id="BookButton" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server"  Text="Book Room"></asp:Button>
  </div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

</form>
```

Edit:

I think its my C# thats wrong - I've been using

```
  string bookRoom = Request.Params.Get("MeetingLength");
```

instead of deserializing the data - how do you read this data in C#?

Any ideas why its not working through AJAX but works fine through a normal POST submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671677/jquery-serialize-and-net-controls) - basically, when you call serialize on .net controls, the jQuery serialize routine uses the name attribute of the control to identify the data. Since this is a .net control, the name property will not be as you expect it to be. If you want a quick fix and you are using .net 4+, you can set the ClientIDMode on the control to correctly set the name client side:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="MeetingLength" runat="server" ClientIDMode ="Static">
    <asp:ListItem Text="15 Minutes" Value="15" Selected="true" /> 
    <asp:ListItem Text="30 Minutes" Value="30" /> 
    <asp:ListItem Text="45 Minutes" Value="45" /> 
    <asp:ListItem Text="1 Hour" Value="60" /> 
    <asp:ListItem Text="1.5 Hours" Value="90" /> 
    <asp:ListItem Text="2 Hours" Value="120" /> 
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Good knowledge but this didn't work - I'm running .NET 4.0 - any other ideas?

Comment: Would it work if I didn't use .NET controls and used regular HTML instead?

Comment: I think the issue here is that the DropDownList control will render a <select> element rather than an input. The data you are sending is using an :input selector.

Comment: How would you suggest rectifying this

Comment: Is it just the MeetingLength value that you want to serialize and send? If so, you could just create the data yourself, something like this might work in your ajax post: data: { "MeetingLength": $("#MeetingLength option:selected").val() }

Comment: please see my updated question, I think its my C# thats wrong

Answer (score 0):

you have to `serialize` the form not the input

insted of

```
data: $("#BookRoom :input").serialize()
```

try

```
data: form.serialize()
```

**Edit**

if you want only the `MeetingLength` value to be sent in the ajax call. just set that as data. try these

```
data: $('#MeetingLength').val()
```

or

```
data: $.param({ MettingLenght : $('#MeetingLength').val()});
```

**Edit 2**

Follow this article. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Make-AJAX-Call-to-ASP.Net-Server-Side-Web-service-method-using-jQuery.aspx

and also place the content type in your ajax call

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
```

Comment: I don't want to submit the whole form

Comment: do you want to send only the `MeetingLength` value?

Comment: yes, only the MeetingLength value :)

Comment: J Subaash This doesn't work, I still have the same original problem

Comment: then please post the network request and the server post method code. and also make sure `'#MeetingLength'` id is correct.

Comment: I think I've found my problem...I've been retrieving the data using this:     string bookRoom = Request.Params.Get("MeetingLength"); instead of deserializing the data - how do you read this data in C#?

Comment: I couldn't really follow this, how would I use this in relation to my code?